# Remove a Table from MXD Data frame (ArcMap Desktop)

Tags: python-2.7, arcpy, arcmap

I need to remove a Table from the data frame of the particular mxd file.

Found this link https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/removetableview.htm

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
    for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
        for tbl in arcpy.mapping.ListTableViews(mxd, "", df):
            if tbl.name.lower() == "TableName":
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveTableView(df, tbl)
    
    mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Project\Project2.mxd")
    
    del mxd
```

This code runs without an error but does not remove the table from the data frame.

Instead of `mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Project\Project2.mxd")` I tried `mxd.save()` also but still no success...

The Table I need to remove during the script process, is a generated output from the Find Identical tool.

Please, note I do not need to delete the table, it just needs to be removed from the Data Frame and save the mxd without the table.

Any Ideas what needs to be added or changed??

Comment: Does it work when you open the MXD in ArcMap and run the code directly in the Python console?

Comment: isshp Thanks for your response! I tried the way you suggested, in opened project python console mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Project\Project2.mxd") created another project2.mxd but the table still remained, so didn't work. mxd.save() option didn't work because the document was opened.

Comment: But before saving to a new file, did it remove the table view from the active MXD?

Comment: No. It does not remove the table view not from the active NXD nor from the new MXD.

Comment: Sorry, your code works succesfully for me. BTW, I just noticed this line in your code: `if tbl.name.lower() == "TableName"`. If you're using `lower()` then this condition will always return False because "TableName" is not lower case.

Comment: So, you mean, if I use lowercase like "tablename" it should work? I tried that but the same result, the table remained after opening the mxd. I tried it in non-active mxd, because this is the way I need it to use.

Comment: Depends on the name of your table. In general, you need to isolate the real issue. Check each step separately, not all of them together: (1) Does your code identify the table view it should remove? (2) Does it remove it successfully? (3) Does it work if you save the MXD as a copy? Start from the Python console in ArcMap in order to work interactively and see the results of each step.

Comment: isshp Thanks for your kind response. I will get back to this problem later after I solve a more urgent problem, which I am going to post now.